# Select the fastest time for each athlete

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-postgresql

I'm trying to generate a list of the best result of each athlete, ordered on time.

Currently I'm just throwing out every duplicate result after getting all results and ordering on time.

I have the following two models:

```
class Athlete(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Result(models.Model):
    athlete = ForeignKey(Athlete, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    time = models.DurationField()
```

Say the Result table looks like this:

```
athlete         time   
-------         ----
1               15.00
1               14.00
2               16.00
2               18.00
2               13.00
3               12.00
```

How do I get the fastest time for each athlete and then sort the list on time?
Like this:

```
athlete         time   
-------         ----
3               12.00
2               13.00
1               14.00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use annotation for this, like:

```
from django.db.models import Min

Athlete.objects.annotate(
    time=Min('result__time')
).order_by('time')
```

The `Athlete` objects that arise from this queryset will have an extra attribute `.time` with the minimum `time` of the *related* `Result` objects. We furthermore use a `.order_by(..)` to then order the results by the `time` annotation.

Django will process this with a query that looks like:

```
SELECT athlete.*, MIN(result.time) AS time
FROM athlete
LEFT OUTER JOIN bar ON athlete.id = result.athlete_id
GROUP BY athlete.*
ORDER BY time ASC
```

In case an `Athlete` has no related `Result`s, its `time` will be `None`.

In case there are `Athlete` with no related results, and `Athlete`s with related results, it depends on the database where it will order the `NULL`s (before the ones with values, or after the ones with values). You can resolve that by specifying how to order with `NULL`s by using [**`nulls_first`** or **`nulls_last`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-to-sort-null-values) in an `F` expression. For example:

```
from django.db.models import F, Min

Athlete.objects.annotate(
    time=Min('result__time')
).order_by(F('time').asc(nulls_last=True))
```

this will order `Athlete`s without any results at the end of the `QuerySet`.

Comment: Thank you! If `Result`  has extra fields like 'competition', can I filter on that field using this method? So I can create the same list, but for a specific competition.

Comment: @RubenvanErk: yes, in that case it is `Athlete.filter(result__competition='WC Quidditch').annotate(..)`. But this will filter *out* the athletes that did *not* participate. From Django-2.0 and further, you can use `Min('result__time', filter=Q(result__competiton='WC Quidditch'))`, which will *include* non-participating `Athlete`s.

Comment: Yes that works. I'm now using this queryset in a template. Can I retrieve the competition of the annotated time?

Comment: @RubenvanErk: I would let the view pass that to the template as well. It is typically *not* considered very good practice to put "business logic" in the "template layer". That is what the view layer is for.

Comment: I understand, maybe it was a poor example. I'm actually creating a list with the best times for each athlete in a particular event and I want to display on what competition the time was set.

Comment: @RubenvanErk: that makes it more complicated, since basically that means you have to join over a join with the same table. Probably it can be done with a `Subquery`, although I'm not entirely sure.